# How to create a breadcrumb for categories and subcategories using linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

How to create breadcumb for categories with unlimited subcategories which their parent specified with their parentid column?

Imagine the following table entries:

```
id    name      parentid
=========================
1     animal    NULL
2     veg       NULL
3     mineral   NULL
4     doggie    1
5     kittie    1
6     horsie    1
7     gerbil    1
8     birdie    1
9     carrot    2
10    tomato    2
11    potato    2
12    celery    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a recursive function working on the full set is ok then the following should work. 
I threw it together in LINQPad. The magic is the recursive function GetBreadcrumbs. I added a third level "boxer" under doggie.

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<MyEntity>()
    {
        new MyEntity() { Id = 1, Name = "animal" },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 2, Name = "veg" },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 3, Name = "mineral" },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 4, Name = "doggie", ParentId = 1 },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 5, Name = "kittie", ParentId = 1 },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 6, Name = "horsie", ParentId = 1 },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 7, Name = "gerbil", ParentId = 1 },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 8, Name = "birdie", ParentId = 1 },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 9, Name = "carrot", ParentId = 2 },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 10, Name = "tomato", ParentId = 2 },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 11, Name = "potato", ParentId = 2 },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 12, Name = "celery", ParentId = 2 },
        new MyEntity() { Id = 13, Name = "boxer", ParentId = 4 },
    };

    var breadcrumbs = GetBreadcrumbs(list); 
    foreach (var breadcrumb in breadcrumbs)
        Console.WriteLine(breadcrumb);

}

// This is where the Magic happens!
public IEnumerable<string> GetBreadcrumbs(IEnumerable<MyEntity> entities, int? parentId = null)
{
    var parents = entities.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
    var children = entities.Where(x => x.ParentId != parentId);

    foreach (var parent in parents)
    {
        yield return parent.Name;
        foreach (var trail in GetBreadcrumbs(children, parent.Id))
            yield return (parent.Name + " > " + trail);
    }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you should be very careful with use of recursion this way, bad data could lead to an endless loop; that is, if Entity A has a parent Entity B which has a parent Entity C which has a parent Entity A, etc.

Comment: Since the function is continously getting divided in the set of parents and children and only the children gets sent onward, that situation should not occur. By the time it reaches the child with a bad parent, that parent isn't in the sub set.