# How to create breadcrumb for parent and children?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string FullBreadcrumb { get; set; }
}
```

I saw on [How to create a breadcrumb for categories and subcategories using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607715/how-to-create-a-breadcrumb-for-categories-and-subcategories-using-linq)

You could use something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetBreadcrumbs(IEnumerable<MyEntity> entities, int? parentId = null)
{
    var parents = entities.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
    var children = entities.Where(x => x.ParentId != parentId);

    foreach (var parent in parents)
    {
        yield return parent.Name;
        foreach (var trail in GetBreadcrumbs(children, parent.Id))
            yield return (parent.Name + " > " + trail);
    }
}
```

Which actually works really well but what I need is instead of it returning `IEnumerable<string>` I will want it to return `IEnumerable<MyEntity>` with FullBreadcrumb filled in.

It might just be that it's late and I am tired but I am having a hard time getting this to work. I am also not familiar with yield. Any help is extremely helpful.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607715/how-to-create-a-breadcrumb-for-categories-and-subcategories-using-linq?noredirect=1&lq=1) is of use

Comment: @ChrisLallo I put that link in the message already - I am asking how to customize it a bit

Comment: I am unsure of the breadcrumb terminology, and there for find it unclear what you are actually asking

Comment: @MichaelRandall I am trying to show a dropdown that basically shows Parent Hierarchy for example Root > Parent > Child that is what I meant by breadcrumb

Comment: What is "FullBreadcrumb"? BTW, this is a nice, clear explanation of yield: https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/12/yield-return-in-c/

Comment: @seesharper FullBreadcrumb is just the Root > Parent > Child that I need it to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve this myself but if someone else wants to know I did it like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetBreadcrumbs(IEnumerable<MyEntity> entities, int? ParentNodeId = null)
        {

            var childNodes = entities.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == ParentNodeId);
            foreach (var currentNode in childNodes)
            {
                var parent = entities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentNode.ParentCategoryId);
                var childrens = entities.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == currentNode.Id);

                currentNode.FullBreadcrumb = string.Format("{0}{1}", (parent == null ? null : parent.FullBreadcrumb + " > "), currentNode.Name);
                yield return currentNode;
                foreach (var trail in GetBreadcrumbs(entities, currentNode.Id))
                {
                    yield return trail;
                }
            }
        }
```